# How to dynamically add <a> in a html table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table generated from an array. I'm looking to add a hyperlink to the entire first column of the `<tbody>` and only the first column.

I am able to add the `<a>` after the table is created, but then it doesn't actually contain the url within it, it simply appends to what already exists.

1. Specifically, how can I add a hyperlink to the first column of the
   `<tbody>`?
2. Generally, as the table is being made, how can I specify different
   things (anchors, classes, styles, etc.) for different columns?

http://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/n357gqo9/10/

```
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTable)
    .table();
});

//TABLE MADE USING for
function buildTable(tableArray) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
  var tbodyID = tableBody.setAttribute('id', 'tbody');

  for (var i = 0; i < tableArray.length; ++i) {
    var column = tableArray[i];
    var colA = column[0];
    var colB = column[1];
    var colC = column[2];
    var colD = column[3];


    if (colA != "") {
      var row = document.createElement('tr');
      var getTbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
      for (var j = 0; j < column.length; ++j) {

        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(column[j]));
        row.appendChild(cell);
        //NEXT TWO LINES DO NOT WORK
        var firstCol = getTbody.rows[i].cells[0];
        firstCol.setAttribute('class', 'TEST');
      }
    }
    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);

  /* WORKS AFTER TABLE IS CREATED BUT CAN'T CAPUTRE INTERNAL LINK
  var getTbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    for (var i = 0; i < getTbody.rows.length; i++) {
      var firstCol = getTbody.rows[i].cells[0]; //first column
        //firstCol.style.color = 'red'; 
        //firstCol.setAttribute('class', 'TEST');
        var link = document.createElement('a');
       firstCol.appendChild(link);


    }
*/
}
```

Comment: When `i` is `0` and `j` is `0`, `cell` will be the first column in the first row.

Comment: What about the first column in all rows? That's where I'm having some trouble. `rows[i].cells[i]`?

Comment: `cell` is the first column of the row when `j` is `0`. The idea is that `i` represent's the row's index and `j` the column's index (zero based index for both).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not understanding. I  tried `cell.setAttribute('class', 'TEST');` and it applied it to every single `td`, not just the first `td` of each `tr`. I tried `cell[0]` and `cell[j]` without any luck (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined`). Could you give me the idiot-proof, plain English version?

Comment: You need something like `if (j == 0) {cell.classList.add("TEST")}` this will add the class `TEST` only to the first cell of every row. To do that to only the first cell of the first row use `if (i == 0 && j == 0) {cell.classList.add("TEST")}`. I hope you get de idea now

Comment: Gotcha. I appreciate you walking me through it.